# apt-get keeps wanting to download a package, overriding my decision

Tags: 14.04, apt, nvidia, package-management

I've recently had a problem with the graphics on my laptop. I am currently trying a working nvidia driver, as my computer had problems with the previous one. When I try to issue any install command for any nvidia driver, apt get overrides my decision and installs a custom nvidia driver version (nvidia-340 to be precise). How can I deselect that package from command line?

Comment: "apt get overrides my decision" ... what decision? How have you informed apt of your decision?

Comment: I type apt get install nvidia-331 and apt get says it will install nvidia-340 ignoring my request to download version 331

Comment: Have a closer look at [what nvidia-331 really is](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nvidia-331).

Comment: Pardon my syntax but I'm typing from my phone because my laptop is currently "work in progress"

Comment: Oh so that package is just a "pointer" to install a newer version?

Comment: Indeed. If you really need an older driver, you'll have to go for [nvidia-304](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nvidia-304). Anything in between is a transitional package.

Comment: @DavidFoerster done.

Answer (score 1):

[`nvidia-330`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nvidia-331) (actually, all `nvidia-3XX` packages from `nvidia-310` onwards) are transitional packages that actually install `nvidia-340`. If you want an older driver, use [`nvidia-304`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nvidia-304) instead.